# How to specify through a SVG path whether the shape being drawn would have a fill or not like we could do in VML?

Tags: html, svg, vml

I have a very interesting problem at hand. In VML while describing the traversed path of a shape we can specify whether that shape would have a fill or stroke or not. It uses commands like `ns` and `nf` in the `path` declaration to specify that the current set of paths would have `no stroke` or `no fill`. For example:

`wr -21600 0 21600 43200 0 0 21600 21600 l 0 21600 ns x e`

in the above VML path the command `ns` specifies that the current shape would not have a stroke.

Can we do something similar in SVG?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using CSS approach how to set an image to fill a path in SVG?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914868/using-css-approach-how-to-set-an-image-to-fill-a-path-in-svg)

Comment: @PaulSweatte the question you linked is not a duplicate of my question because I don't need CSS approach to set fill and stroke of my shape. Doing this would mean I would have to split my path (which is a combination of many paths drawing mutually exclusive shapes). Instead what I wanted was a way to specify the fill and stroke of my individual shapes in that combination of shapes.

Comment: Do you know of another way to set fill and stroke directly on a path in SVG? VML has the [path element](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-VML#h2:specification), and SVG has the [polyline element](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2013/04/06/getting-started-with-svg-an-example-driven-exploration-of-basic-svg-usage-in-xhtml.aspx).